# Modeling stated preference alternative labels vs alternative characteristic levels

Tags: multinomial-distribution, mlogit, conjoint-analysis

I have data from a stated preference survey in which each respondent answers 3 questions each with 
3 alternatives.

- A status_quo / opt-out alternative is the first option for all questions.
- The remaining 2 alternatives each have 3 characteristics (Char1, Char2, Price).
- There are 2 numeric levels that Char1 can take in any given question and Char2 has 3 possible        numeric levels, resulting in 6 unique combinations of Trait1 and Trait2 that can appear together.
- Lets stay we label those unique combinations as Bundle1, Bundle2, ... Bundle6.

  I think in most choice experiments like this, one would end up modeling the choice as a 
  function of Trait1 and Trait2 levels and a constant for the status-quo alternative.

  - choice ~ I(if status_quo_chosen) + Trait1 + Trait2 + Price

My question is, would it be valid to instead estimate a model of choice as a function of the Bundles where those variables would be defined as binary (0,1) if that particular bundle was chosen when it appeared in a question.  Something like:

- choice ~ I(if status_quo_chosen) + Bundle2 + Bundle3 + Bundle4 + Bundle5 + Bundle6 + Price